# RestTemplate with basic authentication on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-security, resttemplate

I have develop a Spring MVC Rest service on Google App Engine with Spring Security 3.1.

Since the service will be available only to my other apps, I have a basic authentication setup with predefined username and password.

Now, I have a client developed with RestTemplate. But I am not able to find a way to access my services securely with username and password, sent via RestTemplate.

I have gone through many articles, but most are using Apache HttpClient (not supported by google appengine).

SO, is there any alternatives to getting what i want on google appengine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RestTemplate basic or digest Authentication with the current httpclient (4.x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376549/resttemplate-basic-or-digest-authentication-with-the-current-httpclient-4-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Basic Auth with URLFetch as this is supported by google, though you want to have the ssl enabled to for use Basic Auth.

You might want to see at this link, though not for appengine but should be good.

http://www.jpalace.org/docs/technotes/spring/rest-security.html