# Basic authentication for REST API using spring restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, jira-rest-api

I am completely new in RestTemplate and basically in the REST APIs also. I want to retrieve some data in my application via Jira REST API, but getting back 401 Unauthorised. Found and article on [jira rest api documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication) but don't really know how to rewrite this into java as the example uses the command line way with curl. I would appreciate any suggestion or advice how to rewrite:

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31"
```

into java using spring rest template. Where the ZnJlZDpmcmVk is a base64 encoded string of username:password. Thank you very much.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376549/resttemplate-basic-or-digest-authentication-with-the-current-httpclient-4-x

Comment: curl supports authentication out of the box, you just need to tell it username and passoword `curl -u fred:fred`, no need for clunky manual headers. The same goes for Spring.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Taken from the [example on this site](http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/02/quick-tip-basic-authentication-with-spring-resttemplate), I think this would be the most natural way of doing it, by filling in the header value and passing the header to the template.

This is to fill in the header `Authorization`:

```
String plainCreds = "willie:p@ssword";
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
```

And this is to pass the header to the REST template:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<Account> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Account.class);
Account account = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me. I had to point out that if you do not want to use the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 class and you would like to use the android Base64 class instead: import android.util.Base64;, you can replace the one line above with this:  byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encode(plainCredsBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: java 8 you can use Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString()

Comment: with HttpHeaders from spring-web:6.0.10, you can also write 
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setBasicAuth(user, password);`

Answer (score 126):

You may use spring-boot [RestTemplateBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html)

```
@Bean
RestOperations rest(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthentication("user", "password").build();
}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-resttemplate)

(before SB 2.1.0 it was `#basicAuthorization`)

Comment: Thanks! This is the fastest and easiest way.

Comment: It is not a good solution as it would add an authorization header to each and every request sent through `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 53):

There are multiple ways to add the basic HTTP authentication to the `RestTemplate`.

#### 1. For a single request

```java
try {
    // request url
    String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    // create auth credentials
    String authStr = "username:password";
    String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authStr.getBytes());

    // create headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

    // create request
    HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

    // make a request
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

    // get JSON response
    String json = response.getBody();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you are using Spring `5.1` or higher, it is no longer required to manually set the authorization header. Use `headers.setBasicAuth()` method instead:

```java
// create headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth("username", "password");
```

#### 2. For a group of requests

```java
@Service
public class RestService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .basicAuthentication("username", "password")
                .build();
    }

   // use `restTemplate` instance here
}
```

#### 3. For each and every request

```java
@Bean
RestOperations restTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthentication("username", "password").build();
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Best answer. Each for it's kind.

Comment: Being on Spring 5.2 I just loved to see the phrase "If you are using Spring 5.1 or higher..." - yes please, finally!

Answer (score 34):

As of Spring 5.1 you can use `HttpHeaders.setBasicAuth`

Create Basic Authorization header:

```
String username = "willie";
String password = ":p@ssword";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
...other headers goes here...
```

Pass the headers to the RestTemplate:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<Account> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Account.class);
Account account = response.getBody();
```

Documentation: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#setBasicAuth-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 27):

(maybe) the easiest way without importing spring-boot.

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("user", "password"));
```

Comment: Beware that using interceptors has a consequence that streaming no longer works.  Here's why: `exchange()` -> `doExecute()`, -> `createRequest()`, -> `InterceptingHttpAccessor.getRequestFactory()` (since `RestTemplate` extends `InterceptingHttpAccessor`).  If there are interceptors, `getRequestFactory()` returns an  `InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory`, which creates `InterceptingClientHttpRequest`s.  These extend  AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest`, which converts the input stream to a byte[] (to hand off to the interceptors). So, an InputStream is not actually streamed.

Comment: This approach is now deprecated. Use BasicAuthenticationInterceptor instead.

Answer (score 18):

Reference Spring Boot's `TestRestTemplate` implementation as follows:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/TestRestTemplate.java

Especially, see the addAuthentication() method as follows:

```
private void addAuthentication(String username, String password) {
    if (username == null) {
        return;
    }
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = Collections
            .<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> singletonList(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(
                    username, password));
    setRequestFactory(new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(getRequestFactory(),
            interceptors));
}
```

Similarly, you can make your own `RestTemplate` easily

by inheritance like `TestRestTemplate` as follows:

https://github.com/izeye/samples-spring-boot-branches/blob/rest-and-actuator-with-security/src/main/java/samples/springboot/util/BasicAuthRestTemplate.java

Answer (score 6):

Instead of instantiating as follows:

```
TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
```

Just do it like this:

```
TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(user, password);
```

It works for me, I hope it helps!

Comment: TestRestTemplate doesn't seem to working after upgrading spring boot to 1.3.x

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be used for unit tests not release code?

Answer (score 3):

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
```

then continue with the same procedure mentioned by the others here:

```java
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty much just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835298).

Answer (score 1):

Use `setBasicAuth` to define credentials

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth("myUsername", myPassword);
```

Then create the request like you prefer.

Example:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, 
request, String.class);
String body = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394971 answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm using spring version `5.3.15` for my unit test environment. I used `withBasicAuth` for my tests :

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTestClass {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    ...
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void TestGetSettings(){
        DtoClass dtoClass  = this.restTemplate
                           .withBasicAuth(UserServices.DEFAULT_USER, UserServices.DEFAULT_PASSWORD)
                           .getForObject(String.format("http://localhost:%d/setting",
                port), DtoClass.class);
        assertThat(dtoClass.getClientAddress()).isNotEmpty();
    }
   ...
}
```

As you see this method only work for basic authentication. If you look at the details of the `withBasicAuth` method, you will find that the method source will be like this:

```java
// TestRestTemplate.java file: 
...
public class TestRestTemplate {
    ... 
    private final RestTemplateBuilder builder;
    ...
    public TestRestTemplate withBasicAuth(String username, String password) {
      TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate(this.builder, username, password, this.httpClientOptions);
      ...
    }
}
```

As a result, for other types of authentication you can use the `RestTemplateBuilder` as a builder which is mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Step By Step

I added **Client Credentials** In application.Properties file like below...

http.basicauth.username = yourUserName
http.basicauth.password = yourPassword

And , Then I created one class With two fields Because I'm loading those two fields from the Application.Properties file : **username** and **password** . Make sure your class is annotated with **@Component**..

```
@Value("${http.basicauth.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${http.basicauth.password}")
private String password;
```

And Then , You need to **autowired** above class From Wherever you want..

```
// I'm getting a username and password from application.properties file 
String userCredentials = referenceClassName.getUsername()+":"+referenceClassName.getPassword();
// Encoded User Credentials and Convert it into a String                        
String encodedUserCredentials= Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(userCredentialsBytes.getBytes());        
headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " +base64UserCredentials);

HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
String url = "externalUrl";
// Getting a Json String body
String body = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,request,String.class).getBody();

 Note :: For getting an Access Token from String Json body  , That's why  I converted it into a Json Object
 JsonObject tokenJsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(body).getAsJsonObject();
// Getting access token as string from tokenJsonObject
String accessToken = tokenJsonObject.has("access_token") && !tokenJsonObject.get("access_token").isJsonNull() ? tokenJsonObject.get("access_token").getAsString() : "";
```

If you have any concerns, please let me know in comments..Hope It will helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

`I have been using Spring above 5.1.x`

```
// create headers for basic auth

var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth("username", "password");
```