# RestTemplate (or WebClient) per destination socket and connect timeouts

Tags: spring, resttemplate, apache-httpcomponents

Is there a way with either client (`RestTemplate` or the newer `WebClient`) to set per destination socket or connect timeouts? For example in an API aggregation web service, where I talk to several different services/hosts, it's often desirable to have different socket timeouts based on if the services are internal or external/3rd party. The only solution I know of (with `RestTemplate`, I haven't used `WebClient`) is to instantiate a separate `RestTemplate` with a different socket timeout/connect timeout (and do this for each host that requires a different timeout).

This is fairly annoying because the amount of setup code required for a `RestTemplate` configured with `HttpComponents` is non-trivial, and having to add `@Qualifier` at every use of `RestTemplate` injection is also non-ideal. Further, the fact that `HttpComponents` allows for max total connections and max routes to host implies that one RestTemplate talking to all outbound traffic is the expected usage.

Comment: This question handles a similar problem (auth per host). I'm pretty sure, you can adapt it for your problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957550/spring-boot-rest-template-and-rest-template-builder