# How to mock security context in tests if I disabled authorizarion

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, integration-testing, security-context

I have tests like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    ....
```

In tests I disabled authentification/authorizaton

But in code I use following:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

But it is reason why tests fails.

How can I mock it my tests?

### P.S.

This one doesn't work:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateWithoutNameAndEmail() {
    Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
    SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
    Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    Mockito.when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("aName");

    restTemplate.exchange(..
```

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns null in code

and this one too:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "aUser", roles = { "ADMIN" })
public void testUpdateWithoutNameAndEmail() {
   ...
```

Comment: you can use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()` and pass to it some `Authentication` mock (or a real instance if you want)

Comment: @RC. Where need I write this code?

Comment: @RC. please read topic update

Comment: That's why you should post [mcve], if you use a restTemplate then you are querying some real server. So you need to use a real authentication (username password [basic auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920268/basic-authentication-for-rest-api-using-spring-resttemplate) maybe).

Comment: @RC, I use TestRestTemplate and I wrote it in initial post

Comment: From the javadoc "If you are using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, a TestRestTemplate is automatically available and can be `@Autowired` into your test. If you need customizations (for example to adding additional message converters) use a RestTemplateBuilder `@Bean`." So build a TestRestTemplare with some authentication (username / password)

Comment: @RC. But how to use WithMockUser annotation ? Which classes should I use?

Answer (score 14):

You can mock Spring's `Authentication`:

```
Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
```

And tell Spring's `SecurityContextHolder` to store this `Authentication` instance:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(auth);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
```

Now, if your code needs `Authentication` to return something (the user name perhaps) you just set some expectations on the mocked `Authentication` instance in the usual way e.g.

```
Mockito.when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("aName");
```

There's also a Spring test annotation (`org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser`) which does this for you...

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "aUser", roles = { "anAuthority" })
public void aTest(){
    // any usage of `Authentication` in this test will get an instance withe the user name "aUser" and a granted authority "anAuthority"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have created objects according your description. I did it in the  test begining. But SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() still returns null

Comment: I have added details to topic

Comment: @WithMockUser doesn't wor too

Comment: Might need some more details. The above approaches are valid ways of mocking `SecurityContext` and I cannot reproduce a NPE given the information in your question.

Comment: 1. Do you understand that I use TestRestTemplate for testing?  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()  returns null equals NPE in my topic update