# Spring Boot: Consume Secured API with Basic Authentication

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am pretty sure this was tackled in a different thread, but the ones I came across were not clear at all.

I am just trying to find some good examples or docs as to how you can consume secured RESTful API in Spring Boot; Either with an API key or Basic Auth.

Comment: How about a **web search** for [`spring resttemplate basic auth`](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+resttemplate+basic+auth), leading to articles such as [**Basic Authentication with the RestTemplate | Baeldung**](https://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring) and the StackOverflow question [Basic authentication for REST API using spring restTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21920268/5221149).

Comment: I have already looked at both. I was just hoping I find something more clear by posting this question.

Comment: More clear? That StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920398/5221149) seems very clear. How can it be made clearer? Which part of the six lines of code is unclear?

Comment: I meant more in depth. If I follow that StackOverflow answer you mentioned, I can easily consume a secured API service, but the issue I am not understanding the implications correctly.

Comment: So you want an article about how to do Basic Authentication *in Java* to go deep into what Basic Authentication *is* and how it works? I'd suggest you go read articles dedicated to that topic, instead of expecting a Java-specific article to go that deep. Articles about how to do something in a particular programming language will generally assume knowledge of the underlying subject. It is up to you to gain that underlying knowledge elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of resources. I listed a number of them in this [post on medium](https://medium.com/swlh/react-and-spring-boot-security-b676fe4e9f0c).
This is [my project](https://github.com/xtien/schwartze-frontend). 
I am not the expert on the subject, it's just that I had the same question two months ago.